# ElectronJS code signing with Authenticode

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, code-signing, authenticode

I have looked at electrons docs on how to sign my NodeJS ElectronJS code specifically for windows as im not working on apps for mac at the moment. However the options for obtaining a certificate are very expensive, something like just under $500 a year. I just want to distribute my app without that annoying *windows protected your PC screen*. So would anyone know of any alternatives or something i can do to minimize this cost or even avoid it altogether!

Ive tried surfing the web for multiple options but most seem to be the same thing for the same price.

Comment: There is no other way at the moment. You will need an Extended Validation (EV) to completely remove the smartscreen popup.

Comment: You can reduce a bit the costs using an OV certificate. You will still get the annoying Windows SmartScreen until your application builds up some reputation (essentially by being installed a lot). 
I am facing a related issue with signing macOS tho: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587324/azure-key-vaults-for-code-signing-on-macos