# Azure Key Vaults for Code Signing on macOS

Tags: macos, electron, azure-keyvault, code-signing, electron-forge

I am going to buy a new OV certificate for code signing an Electron application developed by the company I am working for. Since new industry standards, we will need to store it in an HSM, more specifically on a cloud HSM. The application is released for Windows and macOS (both Intel and M1 - two different builds). I am evaluating some vendors that offer Azure Key Vaults as a solution. But I want to know if we can code-sign macOS applications using Azure Key Vaults.

Currently, I am using a standard OV certificate configured with an Apple ID. For macOS, I am using XCode to code-sign an electron application. I am using electron-forge to code sign the macOS version of the application (following the documentation here)

More specifically, we have a Jenkins instance that takes care of the build that runs the electron-forge publish command. Electron Forge is also taking care of publishing the application on a Nucleus instance.

I could not find any documentation saying that Azure Key Vaults can be used with XCode. Also seems like Azure Sign tool is not available for macOS.

I was wondering if there is any solution to code-sign the electron application for macOS with Azure Key Vaults, even using any trusted third-party software.